# Bad allocation or Application exception when calling Evaluate method

Tags: cntk

We are consuming a text model built with CNTK in our service. We are using the CPU in order to classify a word sequence. We are cloning the model function with shared parameters. Every 2-3 days we see a big number of exceptions in our service when calling clonedModelFunc.Evaluate(inputDataMap, outputDataMap, _device). When the exceptions show on a day they appear altogether as bursts.

Do you have any thoughts what might be going on or how we can fix it? We either get ApplicationException or bad allocation exception when calling Evaluate when these exception bursts appear.

Call stack:
System.ApplicationException:
   at CNTK.Function.Evaluate (CNTKLibraryManaged-2.0, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21fff2ec8197defe)
   at CNTK.Function.Evaluate (CNTKLibraryManaged-2.0, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21fff2ec8197defe)
   at

Our method:

```
        var clonedModelFunc = _modelFunc.Clone(ParameterCloningMethod.Share);
```

...
            var inputValue = Value.CreateSequence(vocabSize, seqData, seqStartFlag, _device);

```
        var inputDataMap = new Dictionary<Variable, Value>();
        inputDataMap.Add(inputVar, inputValue);

        Variable outputVar = clonedModelFunc.Output;

        var outputDataMap = new Dictionary<Variable, Value>();
        outputDataMap.Add(outputVar, null);

        clonedModelFunc.Evaluate(inputDataMap, outputDataMap, _device);
```

Comment: Which CNTK version are you using? We have published CNTK 2.0RC1 yesterday. Would you mind to try with the latest bits? If you still see exceptions, could you please give us more information, e.g. whether the exception happens without Cone, details on exception or call stack available, and etc, for further investigation?

Comment: Cool, will update version and if the exceptions go away. Btw I have assumed it is safe to call  _modelFunc.Clone(ParameterCloningMethod.Share); from multiple threads. Please let me know if there is any thread safety issue with the above call.

Comment: It is not always safe to call Clone() from multiple threads.We recomend to to use a model instance pool or syncrhonize Clone() by yourself. The cloned instances can then be used to evaluate multiple requests in a therad-safe way.